# Incorrect division calculation in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In neo4j between queries

```
MATCH (a), (b)
WHERE a<>b
WITH length(shortestPath((a)-[]->(b))) AS dist, a, b
RETURN DISTINCT sum(1.0/dist) AS closeness, a 
ORDER BY closeness DESC
```

and

```
MATCH (a), (b)
WHERE a<>b
WITH length(shortestPath((a)-[]->(b))) AS dist, a, b
RETURN DISTINCT sum(dist) AS closeness, a 
ORDER BY closeness DESC
```

there is no difference. That is `1.0/dist` not working.

For graph

```
CREATE (A {name: "A"})
CREATE (B {name: "B"})
CREATE (C {name: "C"})
CREATE (D {name: "D"})
CREATE (E {name: "E"})

CREATE (A)-[:TO]->(E)
CREATE (A)-[:TO]->(B)
CREATE (B)-[:TO]->(C)
CREATE (B)-[:TO]->(E)
CREATE (C)-[:TO]->(D)
CREATE (E)-[:TO]->(D)
CREATE (D)-[:TO]->(B)
```

Both queries return an answer:

```
"closeness" "a"
2   {"name":"B"}
2   {"name":"A"}
1   {"name":"C"}
1   {"name":"E"}
1   {"name":"D"}
```

I want to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to print out the `dist` values only:

```
MATCH (a), (b)
WHERE a<>b
WITH length(shortestPath((a)-[]->(b))) AS dist, a, b
RETURN dist
```

this returns:

```
dist
1
null
null
1
null
1
null
1
null
null
1
null
null
1
null
null
null
null
null
1
```

So there's no difference between `dist` and `1.0/dist` because of the values. The operator `/` works, just try to return `2.0/dist` and you'll see the results as expected. Hope that helps.